# Clojure: creating a map with switched keys and values from another map

Tags: clojure

I am trying to create a kind of a reverted index from an input `map`. The input map I got is:

```
{"id-1" {"values" ["a" "b" "c"]}, "id-2" {"values" ["a" "b" "c"]}}
```

Then I want to have this other map as result:

```
{"a" ["id-1" "id-2"], "b" ["id-1" "id-2"], "c" ["id-1" "id-2"]}
```

However, I think that my mind did go crazy, and I think I painted myself into the corner without being able of thinking out of the box. Here is what I got so far, and it looks like that it stinks:

```
(->> {"id-1" {"values" ["a" "b" "c"]} "id-2" {"values" ["a" "b" "c"]}}
       (map #(->> (get (second %) "values")
              (map (fn [x y] (hash-map y x)) (into [] (repeat (count (get (second %) "values")) (first %))))
              (apply merge-with concat)))
       (apply merge-with concat))
```

Basically, I use a first `map` used to "iterate" over all my input values. Then I use a second map to create a series of individual maps that looks like that:

```
({"a" "id-2"} {"b" "id-2"} {"c" "id-2"} {"a" "id-1"} {"b" "id-1"} {"c" "id-1"})
```

To get to that map, I create an intermediary array using `into [] (repeat ..)` to feed to the map along with the array of values.

Then I merge them together to get my expected value.

Two issues here:

1. This seems really much more complex than I have the intuition that it is
2. The current end result is not yet perfect since I am getting this:

   {"a" (\i \d - \1 \i \d - \2), "b" (\i \d - \1 \i \d - \2), "c" (\i \d - \1 \i \d - \2)}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this input:

```
(def input {"id-1" {"values" ["a" "b" "c"]}, "id-2" {"values" ["a" "b" "c"]}})
```

it's easier to do:

```
(defn extract [key values]
  (for [v (get values "values")] {v [key]}))

(->> input 
    (mapcat (partial apply extract))
    (apply merge-with concat))
```

or, without an additional function:

```
(->> (for [[k vs] input]
        (for [v (get vs "values")] {v [k]}))
     (flatten)
     (apply merge-with concat))
```

which works the way you intended.

The trick is to wrap `key` in a vector in the `extract` function so `merge-with concat` works without concatenating the strings.

Comment: thanks, it works exactly as intended, and is certainly much much cleaner than what I did. However I am not clear on how `partial` works in that context, could you elaborate a bit on how it works there?

Comment: @Neoasimov It basically creates a function that takes an argument (or more) and then calls `apply extract` with that argument. Is nicer than `#(apply extract %)`, IMHO.

Comment: ok good, thanks for the explanation. Yes, I noticed that variant, and I am analyzing it atm. This example was great for finding new ways working with that kind of data in Clojure, thanks! I got everything I needed and even more :)

Comment: maybe one last question, is there a way to get an array for the resulting values (currently a list; that is another issue I had with my tests). Would need to put `into []` somewhere, but not sure where :|

Comment: Just change the last line to `(apply merge-with (comp vec concat)))`. `concat` creates a lazy sequence, and you can then use `vec` to turn it into a vector.

Answer (score 8):

Using [map destructuring](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20%28Destructuring%29-Map%20binding%20destructuring):

```
(apply merge-with into (for [[k {vs "values"}] input, v vs] {v [k]}))
```

Clearer

```
(apply merge-with into
  (for [[k m] input
        v (get m "values")] 
    {v [k]}))
```

Comment: @a-webb this is really nice! But I am not sure I am fully getting it. Could you explain what happens with `[[k {vs "values"}] input, v vs]`, I think it is the first time I see this destructuring syntax. What I understand is that `k` is bound to the keys `id-x` then `vs` get bound to the vector or values (not sure how `{}` affects the destructuring). But then, the `, v vs`, is this to destructure what you just destructured, so that `v` get bound with the value of the previous destructuring? If so, is there some documentation about this kind of destructuring syntax?

Comment: @Neoasimov This syntax, `(let [{a-value :a} my-map])`, is [map destructuring](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20%28Destructuring%29-Map%20binding%20destructuring), to bind the value of the `:a` key in the map to `a-value`. The `, v vs`, is a continuation of the `for`, as in `(for [row [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]], element row] element) ;=> (1 2 3 4 5 6)`. The comma is just whitespace, more typically you'd see a linebreak and indentation.

Comment: @A.Webb I like this answer substantially better than the accepted one; as a matter of style I like `(for [[k m] input, v (get m "values")] ...)` a bit better, if only because it's a little unusual to use the explicit map-destructuring style.

Comment: +1 Agree, it's better than mine :-) Didn't know that you can use string keys to destructure a hash-map. I always thought it only works with symbols :-(

Comment: @sloth I think you mean *keywords*, not *symbols*. So cute!

Comment: @Thumbnail Of course. I guess I had symbolic identifiers in mind and mixed it up :-)

Comment: @A.Webb Will you please include description of what your code does in the answer? Comments should be used only to suggest improvements to the actual post, they are not a convenient means of long-term storage of useful information. Your code would be of lesser value without explanation.

Comment: @Palec I edited in amalloy's suggestion, with indentation. Should be clearer, but feel free to edit if you like.